# (Pycharm docker setting)Connection refused:no further information

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, docker-for-windows

I'm new to Docker. I get a connecting error when trying to setup Docker in PyCharm Professional edition.

I have followed this [official manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/docker-connection-settings.html) and turn on the checkbox(Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS)
But it still not work.

[image: problem picture]

Cannot connect: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.O.O.1:2375
caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

I have accidentally connected docker one time.But when i restart my computer i cannot connect docker anymore.

Any further help would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are facing `connection refused` then there may be a chance that there is no server to respond to your request.

So first check whether docker server is listening on `2375` port.

```
netstat -anp tcp | findstr 2375
```

Or, use [tcpview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) for GUI.

If docker is not listening on this port, then check your `C:\ProgramData\Docker\config\daemon.json` file and verify whether you have the below Key value pair in your JSON.

```
"hosts": ["tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
```

If it is not there, then add this and restart your docker daemon.

If you are behind a proxy, then make sure to add this in `no-proxy`, so that your requests will not be routed via a proxy server.

**NOTE:** I don't have any experience with `docker on windows`

Comment: Thank you so much.By some reason Windows reserves por 2375 .And I follow this comment. it work for me. https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3546